# how to sync files in linux - command prompt?

Tags: filesystems, synchronization

I see the following files in my directory -

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  401 Oct 12 15:29 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  401 Oct 12 15:29 Makefile~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  336 Oct 12 15:12 testIfaceIndex.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sjos sjos  336 Oct 12 15:12 testIfaceIndex.c~
```

My question is how can I get rid of the file Makefile~ and testIfaceIndex.c~? I have tried the command sync on the folder but it didn't work. how can I sync the files? What is the complete command to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two are ordinary files, judging by the filenames they are probably backups made by a text editor.

The only way to make them go away is to explicitly remove them

```
rm *~
```